# Messenger Chat not working in my react project

Tags: reactjs

i've run out of ideas, i tried to apply messenger live chat to my project but at the closest try i've got blocked by cors policy.

My facebook page is configured well, but i don't know where to apply code. My temporary page is deployed on netlify and got an https because someone says that this might be a problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.